# Bits of precision matrix reconstruction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, computation

We have a real rank $r$ matrix $M\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$.

Suppose we have diagonalized using $LMR=D$.

I want to recover a real matrix $\widetilde{M}$ such that maximum absolute entry of $\widetilde{M}-M$ is atmost $\frac{1}{2}$.

How many bits of precision in $\widetilde{D}$, $\widetilde{L}$, $\widetilde{R}$ suffices so that we can recover $\widetilde{M}$ from $\widetilde{L}^{-1}\widetilde{D}\widetilde{R}^{-1}$?

Comment: Is your LMR the LDU factorization ?  Why $<1/4$ and not $<1/2$ ? If you consider LDU, then the entries of the matrices $L,U,L^{-1},U^{-1}$ are rational numbers with (I think so) numerator and denominator in $O(n)$ or, in the worst case, in $O(n^2)$.

Comment: $L$ refers to Left, $R$ refers to Right. Can we diagonalize with LDU?